# GraphQL React Apollo __typename field not found ( Serverside schema cannot be modified

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I cannot change the serverside schema to include a __typename field. For this query, how do I write the InMemoryCache typeDefs ?

```
EVM(network: eth, trigger_on: head) {
DEXTrades {
  Trade {
    Buy {
      Buyer
      Currency {
        Fungible
        Symbol
        Name
      }
      Seller
      Price
    }
  }
  Transaction {
    Hash
  }
}
```

}

Comment: The __typename field is there as part of the GraphQL spec - you shouldn't need to manually add that.